# ListView with all items having different layout

Tags: android, performance, listview

Do we get any benefits of implementing a `ListView` for which every item would have different layout? Would it be a better idea to put those items into `ScrollView` with `LinearLayout` instead?

Comment: If each item is really that unique that it needs a different layout, it sort of defeats the purpose of the flyweight pattern used by ListView.  So, yeah, I think you'd be better off with a scrolling list with a parent ViewGroup (like LinearLayout) to hold your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it seems like using a `ListView` may still give better performance, though it might be negligible depending on the size of your content.  Because the `ListView` inflates the views as it needs them, it seems like you might save some time by not parsing/rendering views that a user might never see.  A long `ScrollView` with a bunch of views inside seems like it would take additional time when first launched, since the view hierarchy is more complex.

I do think Michael is mostly correct though, that the main advantage of a `ListView` is that views are reused, which saves on memory/processing. Unless you have a ton of content in the `ScrollView`, I suspect the performance difference is not significant, and will almost definitely be more complex -- in particular, having to create an adapter that knows how to create each view type for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you may use ListView for this. Listview is a list of common data using the same layout if you click on it. Users depend on same/similar GUI patterns.

How about **Sliding Tabs** or the newer navigation drawer, link [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).
If you like sliding tabs, then I can give you more details.